# Check for the first char in a text box

Tags: c++, winforms, textbox, c++-cli, startswith

I'm trying to check if a textbox starts with a `-`.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
if(textbox1->Text::StartWith("-"))

if(String(textbox1->Text).StartWith("-");
```

Comment: What library is this "textbox" from?

Comment: Can you define "does not work"?

Comment: What framework are you using? There's no "String" in C++.

Comment: Not enough information. What GUI library do you use?

Comment: I'm using the default project of Visual studio 2010, I guess STDAFX.h

Comment: @kirill : VC++ has Win32, MFC, and WinForms project templates (there is no single default), which all have different mechanisms for doing this. So, you really need to narrow it down more, as it appears you don't even know what _language_ you're working in...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is C++/CLI and WinForms (in which case your question *really* needs retagging),

```
if (textBox1->Text->StartsWith("-"))
```